# Контейнер для хранения абстрактного класса

Tags: c++, указатели, std-list

Пытаюсь использовать list для хранения ссылок абстрактного класса, но компилятор ругается:

```
'Update' is not a member of 'list<IListener *,allocator<IListener *> >::iterator'
```

Код:

```
class IListener {
public:
    virtual ~IListener() {
    }
    virtual void Update()=0;
};

list<IListener*> Listeners;

void CGameModel::NotifyAll() {
    for (list<IListener*>::iterator i = Listeners.begin();
    i != Listeners.end(); i++) {
        i.Update();
    }
}
```

Не могу понять, то ли я неправильно с ним работаю, то ли list просто не может работать со списком указателей на абстрактный класс.

P.S. Прошу из стандарта C++11 function не рекомендовать :)

Comment: ненадо начинать имя переменной с заглавной буквы

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Итераторы надо разыменовывать, так что должно быть `(*i)->Update();`.
`*i` выдает `IListener*`, и через этот указатель вызывается функция `Update`.

Comment: А я пытался так *i->Update(); Спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Если `c++11` всё-таки можно, то я предложу (нет, не `std::function`) использовать диапазонную версию цикла `for`. Код будет выглядеть так:

```
void CGameModel::NotifyAll() {
    for(auto listener : Listeners) {
        listener->Update();
    }
}
```